# how do i create a copy of an object in java, instead of a pointer

Tags: java, pointers, object

Lets say i have an object that i created. I edited some values in it so it is different than the new object() that i referenced. Lets call that object f1. Now i want another object called f2 to be a copy of f1 but not a pointer, so that when i change a value in f2, it does not also change f1. How would i go about doing this in java?

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java

Comment: I beleive you can do it with the clone method if your object implements cloneable. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html for more information

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, have your class implement the `Cloneable` interface. Without this, calling `clone()` on your object will throw an exception.

Next, override `Object.clone()` so it returns your specific type of object. The implementation can simply be:

```
@Override
public MyObject clone() {
    return (MyObject)super.clone();
}
```

unless you need something more intricate done. Make sure you call `super.clone()`, though.

This will call all the way up the hierarchy to `Object.clone()`, which copies each piece of data in your object to the new one that it constructs. References are copied, not cloned, so if you want a deep copy (clones of objects referenced by your object), you'll need to do some extra work in your overridden `clone()` function.

Answer (score 7):

Most objects have a method [clone](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29)() that will return a copy of that object, so in your case

```
f2 = f1.clone()
```

Answer (score 2):

You use [clone](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

Use something like

```
f2 = f1.clone();
```

If you have custom properties (or members), you should override clone in your class to make deep copy. You can learn about shallow and deep copy here

http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-clone-shallow-copy-and-deep-copy/

Answer (score 0):

It is said that using the built in **clone** method has some issues. Therefore it is better to implement another cloning technique.

There is a java library which supports both shallow cloning and deep cloning. It offers deep cloning without the need to implement Serializable.

[**Here**](https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning)

Answer (score -3):

you could clone or if you can't clone you can write your own function for it.

```
function (variable){
   clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(variable))
   return clone;
}
```

Comment: The question is about Java not javascript